# Prove limit of f(x)=x+a using epsilon-delta definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I am trying to prove that $\lim_{x \to 0}(x+a)=a $, using the epsilon delta definition of limits. Here is my attempt:

Let $0<\left | x \right |<\delta $
and $\left | x+a \right |<\varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon>0$

By triangle inequality:

$\left | x+a \right |\leq \left | x \right |+\left | a \right |<\delta +\left | a \right |<\varepsilon\\\\\Rightarrow \delta < \varepsilon-\left | a \right |$

But this is not true for $\varepsilon \leq \left | a \right |$, since that would give a $\delta < 0$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $|x+a| < \epsilon$ is not what you need. If $a=5$ and $x$ is near $0$, $|x+a|$ is not near zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to show:

if $ \epsilon >0$ is given, then there exists $ \delta >0$ such that

$$|f(x)-a| < \epsilon$$

if $0< |x|< \delta.$

Hint: we have $|f(x)-a|=|x|.$

Comment: Thank you, I see it now, I got the definition wrong.